# gtsummary::tbl_summary() remove rows in output

Tags: r, gtsummary, gt

I'm using `gtsummary::tbl_summary()` to create summary tables. Here is an example data:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~grade, ~year,
  "A", "senior",
  NA_character_, " senior",
  "A", NA_character_,
  "B", NA_character_,
  NA_character_, NA_character_,
  "F", "freshmen"
)
```

The data has missing values and these missing values affect the percentages in the summary table

```
df |> tbl_summary()
```

[image]

The percentage for grade A is 50%, NOT 2/6 = 33.3%. The percentages are calculated out of 4 based only on existing records. I wanted to get the percentages out of the entire records so I made the missing values an explicit level.

```
df |> mutate(across(everything(), ~forcats::fct_explicit_na(.x))) |> tbl_summary()
```

[image]

However, now I want to delete those rows with `(Missing)` keeping the same percentages for other levels. How would I remove those rows in the output table? I want something like this in the end.

| Characteristic | N = 6 |
| --- | --- |
| grade |  |
| A | 2 (33%) |
| B | 1 (17%) |
| F | 1 (17%) |
| year |  |
| freshmen | 1 (17%) |
| senior | 2 (33%) |

**edit:** Or is there a more clever way to handle the percentages? Instead of making them an explicit level, is there a way to directly change those percentages? I've tried `missing = "no"` parameter in `tbl_summary()` but the percentages still remain the same

```
df |> tbl_summary(missing = "no")
```

[image]

Comment: gtsummary exports a remove_row_types() function for removing rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we want to senior as n = 2, then we first have to remove the additional white space in the the data frame. The rest is using `remove_row_type()` function as @Daniel D. Sjoberg mentioned in the comments:

```
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~forcats::fct_explicit_na(.x))) %>% 
  mutate(year = trimws(year)) %>% 
  tbl_summary() %>%  
  remove_row_type(variables = c(grade, year), 
                  type = "level", level_value = ("(Missing)"))
```

[image]

Comment: Just to add that I tried to implement this today and it did not seem to work. Once I replaced type = "level" with type="missing" it did. Otherwise, brilliant feedback from all parties :)

Answer (score 2):

```
df |> 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~forcats::fct_explicit_na(.x))) |> 
  tbl_summary() |> 
  remove_row_type(type = "level", level_value = "(Missing)")
```

[image]